# Функция для определения "рабочего времени"

Tags: jquery

Представьте ситуацию:
Допустим есть какой-то магазин, он работает с 09:00 до 17:00.
Нужно написать функцию, которая будет возвращать `true`, если время ПК попадает в это временной промежуток, ну и собственно `false` - если нет.

Примерно представляю как и что должно быть, но в голове путаница..
Подтолкните, плес)

---

Максимум до чего додумался.. (UPD)

```
function TimeMatch(a,b) {
  var a = a.split(':'), b = b.split(':');
  var HHa = a[0], MMa = a[1];
  var HHb = b[0], MMb = b[1];

  if((HH >= HHa && HH <= HHb) && (MM >= MMa && MM <= MMb)) return true; else return false;
}
```

Что-то мне подсказывает, что лучше переводить в миллисекунды и сравнивать так. Прав ли я?

---

p.s. минуты тоже учитывать. (09:30 - 17:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз входные данные представлены с точностью до минуты, то и сравнивать достаточно с той же точностью:

```
const f = (a, b) => {

  const
    m = t => t.split(':').slice(0,2).reduce((a, n, i) => a += + n * (! i ? 60 : 1), 0),
    n = m ((new Date).toLocaleTimeString())

  return n >= m (a) && n < m (b)
}
```